# scroll image with center image zoomed

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, photo-gallery

I want to scroll number of images.When the image comes in center of the iphone it should be zoomed and other images should be small.I tried using openflow project.But I cannot change the photo size.Any other ideas?Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this link.I successfully changed my image size using this project. https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel